# Advice for transformation in mixed models

Tags: regression, mixed-model

I use mixed models (random effect for person; repeated measurements) in lme4 to model a continuous outcome. Predictors are both categorical and continous.

My outcome variable (blood pressure; typically between 100 and 170) has a non-linear evolution over time, which is presented in the figure below.

[image]

code used:

```
model <- lmer(pressure ~ sex + treatment + onset_age + follow_up_time + (1|subject_ID), data=mixed6)
```

[image: residual plot]

[image: qqplot]

[image: the follow_up_time variable (actually named "duration")]

As you can see (figures) my model doesn't satisfy linearity. I have tried the following:
* centering the response variable
* not centering the time variable, i.e using the time variable as it is
* using the logarithm of the time variable.
* adding the square of the time variable (I(follow_up_time ^2)) to the model.

There are >700k observations in the study. 120k individuals.

I've heard that with that many observations, many of the assumptions of linearity become less important.

Any advice on transformations?
Should i convert to generalized mixed models or perhaps the non-linear (nlme?)?
I would really appreciate some opinions on this matter.